# How do I use the "version" property in package.json as the app's directory in grunt?

Tags: node.js, angularjs, gruntjs

I'm managing a project written in angularjs, with the default directory structure, excluding the app directory which uses versioning (ie. "app/0.0.0/", "app/0.1.0/" etc..).

I'm trying to use grunt's package.json file's "version" property to load the correct 
directory so I won't have to manually change the app path in gruntfile.js
but for some reason I keep getting "Cannot GET /" when I run "grunt server".

To better explain this, here's a sample of my gruntfile.js:

```
var yeomanConfig = {
app: 'app/<% pkg.version %>/',
dist: 'dist'
...

grunt.initConfig({
  yeoman: yeomanConfig,
  pkg: grunt.file.readJSON('package.json'),
...
```

If I manually change the app property to "app/0.0.0" it works like a charm
so I'm guessing this has something to do with the templating.

Any ideas?

Thank you very much for the help.

Edit: Thank you for the correction Andreas and Matjaz, but this doesn't solve the problem and gives the same error...
This solves the problem for me but without the templating system:

```
var pkgVersion = grunt.file.readJSON('package.json').version;
// configurable paths
var yeomanConfig = {
  app: 'app/'+pkgVersion,
  dist: 'dist'
};
```

It's pretty ugly but it works. Hoping for a proper solution.

Comment: What about `<%= pkg.version %>`? Notice the "="

Comment: Thanks I accidentally dropped the "=" but even after correcting it , the problem persists.

Answer (score 14):

The best way to handle above scenario is that, In the grunt.initConfig define the package.json

```
grunt.initConfig({
  pkg: grunt.file.readJSON("package.json")
})
```

Once above initialized you can use the properties of the package.json throughout the grunt.js file.

```
<%= pkg.version %>
<%= pkg.homepage %>
```

Comment: That's exactly what I'm doing..

The templating system doesn't seem to work outside grunt.initConfig
therefore you can't use <% %>.

Comment: If it isnt working outside grunt.initConfig try storing it in a variable and reusing it.

Answer (score 3):

To echo data use `<%=`:

```
<%= pkg.version %>
```

Answer (score 2):

I extend the `appConfig` with the name and version:

```
var appConfig = {
    app: require('./bower.json').appPath || 'app',
    name: require('./package.json').name || 'angularapp',
    version: require('./package.json').version || '1.0.0',
    dist: 'dist'
};
```

Then you can access the variables like this:

```
<%= yeoman.name %>
<%= yeoman.version %>
```

For me a clean solution with an optional fallback.